# Gravity Forms and regex - Doesn't seem to validate

Tags: plugin-gravity-forms

I'm attempting to validate a field to ensure it is 9 numerical digits (Canadian SIN number format). I've got the below filter set up:

```
add_filter( 'gform_field_validation_1_1', 'validate_SIN', 10, 4 );
   function validate_SIN( $result, $value, $form, $field ) {
    $pattern = "^\d{3}-?\d{3}-?\d{3}$";
    if ( !preg_match( $pattern, $value ) ) {
        $result['is_valid'] = false;
        $result['message']  = 'value:'.$value.' pattern:'.$pattern.' No Pattern Match';
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Invalid entries fail validation, but valid entries ALSO fail validation. I know the Regex is fine because I've used it before, so I'm at a loss as to why it's not working.

Does anyone have any guidance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you just forgot the delimiters for your pattern.

Try declaring your `$pattern` like:

```
$pattern = "/^\d{3}-?\d{3}-?\d{3}$/";
```

Comment: Amazing. Thank you kind stranger. Completely forgot the delimiters.

Comment: @r3lai I'm glad I could help. Accept my answer, please.